# uninstaller not deleting registry

Tags: registry, nsis, uninstallation

```
Function Check32or64BitWindows
${If} ${RunningX64}
      strcpy $INSTDIR "$PROGRAMFILES64\${APP_FULL_PATH}" 
      SetRegView 64

${Else}
       SetRegView 32
       strcpy $INSTDIR "$PROGRAMFILES32\${APP_FULL_PATH}"
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

If an older version is detected then I execute

```
ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\uninst.exe" /S' $0
```

My uninstall section:

```
Section uninstall
!define APP_UNINST_KEY "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${APP_VENDOR} ${APP_NAME}"
!define APP_UNINST_ROOT_KEY "HKLM"
DeleteRegKey ${APP_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${APP_UNINST_KEY}"
SectionEnd
```

```
Section -Post
WriteRegStr ${APP_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${APP_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayName" "${APP_FULL_NAME}"
SectionEnd
```

Post section creates the registry entry in the windows 64bit registry view but uninstaller is not deleting the registry entry.

If I remove the check for 64bit OS, then creation and deletion of registry in Wow6432Node works correctly.

Comment: Are you installing a x64 application?

Comment: Please be more careful with your formatting. You get a preview as you work and a toolbar which can help with most of the formatting. I've fixed it mostly, but it still needs work.

Comment: And I'd hope that an uninstaller wouldn't delete the registry ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are not installing a x64 application you should not use SetRegView/$PROGRAMFILES64 at all.

If you are installing a x64 application and you called `SetRegView 64` during install you also have to call `SetRegView 64` in the uninstaller.

Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to investigate other registry issues...

Answer (score 5):

The NSIS tutorials I've found place the 64-bit installer logic in a function `.onInit` which is called automatically when the install starts.

Logically, one would try to call this manually in the uninstall section via `Call .onInit`, but NSIS compilation will fail because the function name doesn't start with `un.`.

So, logically, if you create an `un.onInit`, it should "Just work".  And it does.

```
Function un.onInit
${If} ${RunningX64}
    ; Comment out this next line in production environment
    MessageBox MB_OK "This is a 64-bit os, applying work-arounds"
    SetRegView 64
    StrCpy $INSTDIR "$PROGRAMFILES64\My FooBar Application"
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

... and if you are wondering "Why create a duplicate function?", the proper answer to that question is [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Sharing_functions_between_Installer_and_Uninstaller)...